# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Image Ratio

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to create a carousel using bootstrap. I want the images (that have different width and height) to be displayed with a fixed ratio, . Everything I try with CSS breaks and the image ratio breaks and inherit the size of the carousel.

CSS

```
.carousel .item > img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
height: 702px;
max-width: none;
```

}

the html code :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
        <img src="image1.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <img src="image1.jpg"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Should i look for another carousel solution that keeps images' ratio or there is a workaround ?

**EDIT 1 :**

```
    .carousel .item > img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly? do you want to stretch the images to the container size or just to fill the width?

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you're trying to do? Width at 100% and height follow?

```
.carousel .item > img {
   min-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: well , i fixed the issue , a fixed height and auto width.

Answer (score 0):

New Bootstrap 4 Carousel wont honor the `height:auto` fix since it uses flexbox, so you must calculate the height of the element proportionally and in most cases the initial dimensions are unknown so you must use JS to calculate or use position absolute on the image and that opens a new can of worms, but if you are looking for a dirty fix I suggest this

```
.carousel-item img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 68vw; /* play with this */
    }
```

Demo https://codepen.io/nodws/pen/gRozMM